# getting a hidden element and sending it to a different URL

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I'm doing a challenge which requires me to get an ID of element (from the source code - its hidden there - in my example called token), and then re-send it to another page with POST request included. however the code will not keep going to the 2nd request(the POST one) some why and it won't throw an error on the console.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onload = handleResponse;
req.open('get','/example/ex1',true); // will open the page /example/ex1
req.send(); // sends the request
function handleResponse() {
    var token = this.responseText.match(/name="token" value="(\w+)"/)[1];
    var changeReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    changeReq.open('post', '/example/ex2', true);
    changeReq.send('token='+token+'&user=admin')
};
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: no error on the console, but what does your troubleshooting tell you? putting in console.log statmetns to check values, checking the network tab in your web inspector.... There are a myriad of ways to troubleshoot your own code besides error statements

Answer (score 0):

check the network tab. make sure the target URL is called.